# SharePoint - How to remove the Calendar Title

Tags: sharepoint, calendar

I use Script Editor to add stylesheet to minimize my calendar. However, I'm seeking for the solution to remove the calendar header

Example: the word "Calendar" in example image http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-dYs-jxn0GWc/UuF42f6uMbI/AAAAAAAACJw/QHtT1Q2vdNQ/s1600/longdayname.png

```
<style> 
/**** Small Calendar ***/ 
.ms-acal-item{FONT-SIZE: 10px !important} 
.ms-acal-item{height: 18px !important}
.ms-acal-summary-itemrow TD DIV {height: 15px !important} 
.ms-acal-ctrlitem, /*Remove More Items*/ 
.ms-acal-month-top span{display: none} /*Remove Day Header*/
TR TD DIV.ms-acal-today { BORDER-TOP-COLOR: GREEN !important; COLOR: white 
!important; BORDER-BOTTOM-COLOR: GREEN !important; TEXT-DECORATION: none; BORDER-RIGHT-COLOR: GREEN !important; BACKGROUND-COLOR: GREEN; BORDER-LEFT-COLOR: GREEN !important
} /*Focus Today*/
div#AsynchronousViewDefault_CalendarView {width:500px}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
span[Title="Calendar"] { display:none }
```